# jQuery .remove Not Working on Dynamic Field - It Just Appends the Field to the End

Tags: jquery

I have a form group, which, put simply, looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addnewcab").on("click", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    var clonedGroup = $(this).parents(".cabinetgroup");
    $(this).parents(".cabinetgroup").clone(true).appendTo(".cabinetfields");

    clonedGroup.find(".addnewcab").removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-danger").removeClass("addnewcab").addClass("removecab").html("<span aria-hidden='true'>&minus;</span>");

    $(".removecab").on("click", function(eve) {
      eve.preventDefault();
      $(this).parents(".cabinetgroup").remove();
      return false;
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='cabinetform'>
  <div class='cabinetfields'>
  <div class='cabinetgroup'>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <label for='cabinet' class='sr-only'>Storage Cabinet</label>
      <select id='cabinet' name='cabinet' class='form-control cabinput' role='Listbox'>
        <option value='0' disabled selected>Storage Cabinet</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button class='btn btn-success addnewcab'>
       <span aria-hidden='true'>&plus;</span>
    </button>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <label for='quantity' class='sr-only'>Number</label>
      <input type='text' id='quantity' name='quantity' class='form-control cabinput'>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <label for='packsize' class='sr-only'>Pack Size</label>
      <input type='text' id='packsize' name='packsize' class='form-control cabinput'>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, while the function to clone the ".cabinetgroup" works fine, when you click on the button with modified classes - specifically ".removecab" - in any cloned ".cabinetgroup", all it seems to do is append the group rather than remove it.

How can I modify the script so that when a button with the ".removecab" class simply removes the associated group form groups?

Comment: The clone doesn't appear to work as there is no `.cabinetgroup` element. I would guess that your issue is due to the nested `click` handlers, which should be avoided. It seems like you need a delegated event handler, although it's hard to day where exactly without seeing a working version of your code.

Comment: Thanks Rory, sorry, it's a bit all over the place with php and bootstrap code at the same time, so it's hard to get a working version across. There is a `.cabinetgroup` element in there, I just missed it in the original code I'm afraid.

As for nested click handlers, this was the only way I could find to get the `.removecab` class to have any response at all. Is there another way I should assign a function to the button which only appears once the original `.addnewcab` button has been pressed?

Comment: this is very strange indeed. I simplified your code a bit so it becomes more readable. http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/708511/    This does not fix the problem tho. It feels like jquery is not noticing the classes on the button has changed. The listener for ".removecab" doesnt get called at all.